# How to link two integer values in different functions in c while coding arays?

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a pretty basic generator function for c, but currently am getting a floating point error as a result of not linking my integers between two different functions? how would one link the two different integers to always have the same value?
The first integer(currentsize) is meant to change within its defining function. The second integer(nounsize) exists within a different function that is called after.
Here is my code:

```
char ** populate(char ** words, FILE *fptr, int *currentsize, int *maxsize)
{
    int i,j;
    for (int i= 0; i <= *maxsize; i++)
    {
        words[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    }
    while(fscanf(fptr,"%s",words[*currentsize])==1)
    {
        if(*currentsize>=*maxsize)
            words=doubleIt(words,maxsize);
    }
    return words;
}

char* generateSentence(char ** noun, int nounsize)
{
    char *sent = malloc(sizeof *sent * 100);
    strcpy(sent, noun[(rand()%nounsize)]);
    free(generateSentence);
}
```

Thanks for any possible input or advice you can offer.

Comment: "*linking my integers between two different functions*". It's not clear what that means. Please give complete code as a [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: first thing: did I see wrong or are you trying to free a function free(generateSentence)???

Comment: If you pass a pointer to the same variable that you pass as the `nounsize` parameter, they should have the same values.

Comment: Why are you passing `currentsize` as a pointer? The function never modifies it, so there's no need to pass by reference.

Comment: Yeah I realize that's wrong( I meant to delete that earlier but forgot

Comment: I meant to modify currentsize in the populate function(it is supposed to increase by every string scanned from the file), then the number of strings is supposed to be transferred onto the int nounsize(which exists in generatesentence).

Answer (score 0):

you have to have a variable in the code that calling these functions

```
 int froodle = 42;
 populate(words, fptr, &froodle, &maxsize);
 .....
 ....
 generateSentence(nountable, froodle);
```

its not clear if you really need to pass `&froodle` to the first call, the code you show just needs froodle